# cant get my while loops working the way i want it to

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

> i am trying to get this code to work properly where if you input a number it will revert you back to the name=input prompt and once you enter alphabetical characters and not numerical characters it will allow you to move on to the next set of code but it keeps returning you to the name = input and doesnt let you through the rest of the code

```
def setup():
    global name
    global HP
    global SP
    global MP
    while True:
        try:
            name = input('can you please tell me your name?  ')
            name2=int(name)
            if  not name.isalpha==True and not name2.isdigit==False:
                break
                
                
        except Exception:
                print('please input your name')
                continue
    
    HP = randint(17,20)
    SP = randint(17,20)
    MP = randint(17,20)
    print('welcome ['+name+':]:  to the moon landing expedition')
```

Comment: ps this is for a school project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem at `name2=int(name)` This causes an exception unless you type all numbers. In turn, this triggers the `Exception` and loops it forever. Your while loop seems fine.

What i think you should do:

```
while True:
    name = input('What is your name')
    isnum = False
    for i in name:
        if i.isnumeric():
            isnum = True
            break
    
    if isnum:
        print('Please type your name.')
        continue
    
    break
```

Comment: but i cant get it to loop if you press a number if that isnt there

Comment: a number that isn't there? @TristanLauzon

Comment: i mean when you press a number key on the keyboard for the input without that peice of code the loop wont actually loop it will take the input as a string

Comment: @TristanLauzon I edited the post. Hopefully it helps.